# Message Dilemma

Tags: windows-10-mobile, email, messaging

I accidentally put my mobile down. The whole back cover came out along with the battery. Once I put the battery back inside and restarted I started receiving all the messages and mails right from January. I would have received about 1000 mails and messages from January.Is there any way to stop this?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open *Settings->Accounts->Your Email and Accounts*.
2. Select your corresponding account.
3. Click manage.
4. Click "*Change mailbox sync setting*".
5. There is an option called **Download email from**.
6. Make sure it is **not** set to "*any time*".
7. Try changing it's value.
8. Sync your email.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this happens when your phone's date and time settings change. Set your date and time correctly, including the time zones, and then synchronize your accounts.

Comment: All my time zones are all upto date

Comment: Did you synchronize all accounts connected to your phone??

Comment: yaa i have done all that stuff